# Create custom user form

Tags: django, django-admin

On Django Admin, the default 'create user' form has 3 fields: username, password and confirm password.

I need to customize the create user form. I want to add the `firstname` and `lastname` fields, and autofill the username field with `firstname.lastname`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name' , 'last_name', )


class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    prepopulated_fields = {'username': ('first_name' , 'last_name', )}

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', ),
        }),
    )


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Hey @mishbah, the following error occurred: u"Key 'first_name' not found in 'UserForm'"

Comment: I'm still getting the same error:   

u"Key 'first_name' not found in 'UserForm'"

Comment: I don't know where you get error for the `UserForm`. In my example, I'm only overriding the `add_form` which is called `UserCreateForm`. What version of django are you using?

Comment: Please could you post your full stacktrace

Comment: The form is working now! But the username separator is "-". The format I need is first_name.last_name

Answer (score 2):

Only `add_fieldsets` is enough. No need to provide the `add_form`.

this would be the full code for `admin.py`, you can read about it [in the Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
            (
                None,
                {
                    'classes': ('wide',),
                    'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
                },
            ),
        )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

As a side note: `'classes':('wide',),` sets the style of the field to open or "not collapsed", you can read more about the options for that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/)