# Admin Django fieldset creating new user creation form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I have two diffeent fieldsets depending on wether a user is in the 'leader' group or not. The fieldset show exactly what I want, except when I try to add a new user, from a user in the 'Leader' group, I now get a different user creation form. 
I got how to do the different fieldsets from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568921/restricting-django-admin-change-permissions), and I tried ensuring the form is indeed the right one by overriding the custom form as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897480/django-admin-custom-create-user-form).

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'UserProfile'
    fk_name = 'scout_username'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    #ensuring it's the right form
    add_form = UserCreateForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

    fieldsets = (
        ((None), {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                        'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    leader_fieldsets = (
        ((None), {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        )

    #making it so leaders can only view  the fields within leaders_fieldset
    #removing this also removes the problem yet all the fields are shown regardless of the user's group
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='Leader').exists():
            return self.leader_fieldsets
        else:
            return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj=obj)

    #adding the userprofile stuff to the user change form
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

If the user is not in the 'Leader' group I get the original user creation form.
[User Creation Form if user is not in Leader Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q99D.png)

Else I get a form with the fields, `username`, `password` (which is not a password type as anything written in it is clear text) and then I get `first name` and `last name`.
[User Creation Form if user is in Leader Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNGlw.png)

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little trick which worked for this particular case follows the fact that the url always had 'ADD' at the end.
Thus by checking if it was the user-add form currently on the page a function could return true or false.

```
def is_add_form(request):
    path_info = request.META.get('PATH_INFO')
    last_path = str(path_info.split('/')[-2])
    if last_path == 'add':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This worked with great success and I hope it helps others.